# COTS Workshop Registration System

Tags: cots

Does anyone have any experience with any COTS systems for managing workshops and the associated registrations, courses, communications, etc.?

We have a home-built Perl system that is about 8 years old and is currently embedded as an iframe in a SharePoint portal site (externally facing). Needless to say, it isn't integrated into our site well, looks like crap, needs an overhaul, lacks features, etc. It would be nice to find either a product we can install or a service that provides those features.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You might also look into Moodle - it's a platform developed to supplement classroom teaching (or implement online learning courses) but should have all the major features you listed, and would support your needs reasonably well, as well as enhancing your event with an online component such as slide/presentation distribution only to registered users or users that took a particular class, etc)